# Correlation in R of two columns of complete cases - only returning first element of vector?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to complete the following prompt:

Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0. A prototype of this function follows:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
## 'directory' is a character vector of length 1 indicating the location of
## the CSV files

## 'threshold' is a numeric vector of length 1 indicating the number of
        ## completely observed observations (on all variables) required to compute
        ## the correlation between nitrate and sulfate; the default is 0

## Return a numeric vector of correlations

spectdata<- list.files(pattern= ".csv") #creates vector with list of filenames
corr<-function(directory,threshold =0, id = 1:332){
  info<-list()
  for(i in id){
    info<-read.csv(directory[i], header=TRUE)
    NOBS<-sum(complete.cases(info))
    if (NOBS>threshold){
      return(cor(info$nitrate,info$sulfate,use="complete.obs"))
    }

  }
  corr<-sapply(spectdata,corr)
  corr<-unlist(corr[!sapply(corr,is.null)])
  return(corr)
}
cr<-corr(spectdata,threshold =150)     
head(cr)
```

It looks like the program works, but only returns the first element on a 5 element vector:

```
> cr<-corr(spectdata,threshold =150)     
> head(cr)
[1] -0.01895754
```

what it should be:

```
cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
head(cr)
## [1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
```

Anybody have any thoughts? I am quite new to R and am stumped. If I try to define the vector to be longer, I get the same answer (0.01895754 NA NA NA NA), for example.

Comment: This may have many dupes.  Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240049/correlation-between-na-columns)

Comment: There are at least four moving pieces here.  To get a better response, isolate the different pieces and identify the one(s) giving the problem.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should not be asking for the answers a graded assignment in here...

Comment: I have the correct answer, but I am having trouble getting the rest of the vector to come through - it should be maybe 1-2 edits to code. As I'm sure you can see, most of the work is done~

Comment: Please post some input data for a reproducible example. What do .csv files look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unlikely to get the full answer for free, but assuming you want to learn, your function has a lot of issues.

**First** you define the function twice:

```
### corr defined here
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
             spectdata<- list.files(pattern= ".csv") 
             ### corr defined here again!!
             corr<-function(directory,threshold =0, id = 1:332) {
```

**Second** you don't specify where list.files should look:

```
spectdata<- list.files(pattern= ".csv") # you should add directory
                                        # I'll leave it to you to add it
```

**Third** Your function returns multiple arguments:

```
return(cor(info$nitrate,info$sulfate,use="complete.obs")) # 1st return
return(corr)                                              # 2nd return
```

**Fourth** You repeat variable names. Your function is called `corr` and you define a local variable as `corr`:

```
corr <- sapply(spectdata, corr)      ## local variable
```

**MY SUGGESTIONS** *given what you've provided as code*

**First**  Stick with 1 function definition *the first one is fine*
**Second**  Specify the directory where `list.files` should look
**Third**  Return only a single argument.

```
You can make a vector of elements with a for loop like so:

info <- NULL
for (i in 1:4) {
    info <- c(info, i)
}
```

**Fourth**  You don't need `sapply` or `unlist`. Try to make it work without them.
**Fifth**  Use a different variable name for the local variable that conflicts with the function name.

**MOST IMPORTANTLY** Run each command line-by-line and look at each output.

Comment: Thank you Chi! A couple clarifications: the code begins with "spectdata<- list.files(...) - the previous was just the prompt. Second, the spectdata is set to my directory, so calling spectdata does in fact list all of the .CSV files I need. Thirdly, with the multiple arguments, it should follow the if ... else format - this is working correctly.  There should be several correlations that are calculated by this code, but, I'm only getting the first element. I'm not sure how a for-loop would help here ~ I don't think it's writing the remainder of the vector.

Comment: What do you mean by `if...else` format? I only see an `if...`? The fact that you're returning multiple times could be the cause of your problem (get rid of the first return). You have a `for` loop already, in which, you should get a single correlation value from a single file...you simply need to modify it so that you build a vector instead of returning a value. You should only return a value after building the vector of correlations.