# Attempting to merge several .R files and then extrapolate correlations via subsetting

Tags: r

**The challenge**:
Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0.

**The Code**:

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0){
        ## This part creates the list for the creation of coorelation data between Nitrate and Sulfite
        list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
        data1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list, read.csv, header = TRUE))
        ## This provides for interaction between parameters provided and column data
                data1.subO  <- data1[data1$sulfate > threshold, drop = FALSE]
                data1.sub2O <- data1.subO[data1.subO$nitrate > threshold, drop = FALSE]
                data1.sub3O <- na.omit(data1.sub2O)
                print(cor(data1.sub3O))
}
```

**The Errors**:

```
> corr("specdata", 300)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame`(data1, data1$sulfate > threshold, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected In addition: Warning message:
 In `[.data.frame`(data1, data1$sulfate > threshold, drop = FALSE) :
  'drop' argument will be ignored
```

** The Question **:

How do I tell R to I want to correlate information from the 'sulfate' and 'nitrate' columns? Please show examples, explanations, etc. Thank you!``

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240049/correlation-between-na-columns)

Comment: Is there someone who can explain why I cannot subset the data from the "data1" data frame?

Comment: In your function `data1[data1$sulfate > threshold, drop = FALSE]`, I think you need `data1[data1$sulfate > threshold, ,drop = FALSE]`  Similarly for the `data1.subO[data1.subO$nitrate > threshold, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Also, please check if the column names are the correct one by printing the column names of 'data1' and by commenting out the lines below